# Wrap C struct with array member for access in python: SWIG? cython? ctypes?

Tags: python, c, struct, swig, cython

I want to access a C function that returns a struct containing double arrays (where the lengths of these arrays is given by other int members of the struct) from python. The declaration is

```
typedef struct {
  int dim;
  int vertices;
  int quadrature_degree;
  int polynomial_degree;
  int ngi;
  int quadrature_familiy;
  double *weight; /* 1D: ngi */
  double *l;      /* 2D: ngi * dim */
  double *n;      /* 2D: ngi * vertices */
  double *dn;     /* 3D: ngi * vertices * dim */
} element;

extern void get_element(int dim, int vertices, int quad_degree, int poly_degree, element* e);
```

The important point is I want to be able to access all the `double*` members as NumPy arrays of the correct shape (i.e. `dn` should be a accessible as 3D array).

Simply SWIG-wrapping this gives me the struct just fine, but all the `double*` members are `<Swig Object of type 'double *' at 0x348c8a0>` which makes them useless. I played around with the NumPy SWIG interface file but couldn't get any of the typemaps like `( DATA_TYPE* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1 )` to work (I think it's not possible to get them to match in this case but I'd be happy to be proven wrong).

My guess is I'd have to hand code initialization of the NumPy arrays as `PyArrayObject` for these members and SWIG extend my struct to make them accessible in Python? That looks like a lot of work. Can anyone see a nicer way using SWIG? It would be possible to change the struct or the method returning it if that made things easier.

Alternatively I had a look at cython and ctypes. Would these be better suited for what I'm trying to achieve? I haven't used cython so can't judge it's wrapping capabilities. For ctypes I can roughly imagine how to do it, but it means writing by hand what I had hoped a reasonably automated wrapper could do for me.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: How to run this code? I tried `get_element(1,2,3,6)` getting error 
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using SWIG requires a typemap for the entire struct. Tyepmaps for only the pointer members are not enough, since they don't have the context to know what size to initialize the NumPy arrays with. I managed to get what I wanted with the following typemaps (which was basically copy & paste from numpy.i and adapt to my needs, probably not very robust):

```
%typemap (in,numinputs=0) element * (element temp) {
  $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap (argout) element * {
  /* weight */
  {
    npy_intp dims[1] = { $1->ngi };
    PyObject * array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void*)($1->weight));
    if (!array) SWIG_fail;
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,array);
  }
  /* l */
  {
    npy_intp dims[2] = { $1->ngi, $1->dim };
    PyObject * array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void*)($1->l));
    if (!array) SWIG_fail;
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,array);
  }
  /* n */
  {
    npy_intp dims[2] = { $1->ngi, $1->vertices };
    PyObject * array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void*)($1->n));
    if (!array) SWIG_fail;
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,array);
  }
  /* dn */
  {
    npy_intp dims[3] = { $1->ngi, $1->vertices, $1->dim };
    PyObject * array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(3, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void*)($1->dn));
    if (!array) SWIG_fail;
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,array);
  }
}
```

This works different from the C function in that it returns a tuple of NumPy arrays with the data I want, which is more convenient than having to extract it from the `element` object later. The first typemap furthermore eliminates the need to pass in an object of type `element`. Hence I can hide the `element` struct entirely from the python user.

The python interface finally looks like this:

```
weight, l, n, dn = get_element(dim, vertices, quadrature_degree, polynomial_degree)
```

Comment: Can you show the full interface file here? I don' t get the expected result.

Comment: @xgdgsc You can find it [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~florian-rathgeber/fluidity/femtools-python-swig-tuple/view/head:/femtools/get_element.i)

Comment: Thanks! Now my program in python crashes when accessing one of the returned results, what could be the cause?

Comment: @xgdgsc There's any number of reasons why your program might crash e.g. if the struct returned by your C function isn't properly initialized, but I don't think this is the place to discuss it. Also I'm no longer using SWIG and moved over to Cython (see Fabrizio's answer).

Answer (score 10):

Cython rules:

```
cdef extern from "the header.h":

ctypedef struct element:
  int dim
  int vertices
  int quadrature_degree
  int polynomial_degree
  int ngi
  int quadrature_familiy
  double *weight
  double *l
  double *n
  double *dn

void get_element(int dim, int vertices, int quad_degree, int poly_degree, element* e)
```

and then you can interface it, from python space

Answer (score 1):

Check out SWIG's typemaps. They let you write your own code for handling specific types, specific instances (type+name) or even groups of arguments. I haven't done it for structures, but to specially handle a case where the C function takes an array and its size:

```
%typemap(in) (int argc, Descriptor* argv) {
    /* Check if is a list */
    if (PyList_Check($input)) {
        int size = PyList_Size($input);
        $1 = size;
        ...
        $2 = ...;
    }
}
```

That will take the pair of arguments `int argc, Descriptor* argv` (since the names are provided they have to match as well) and pass you the PyObject used and you write whatever C code you need to do the conversion. You could do a typemap for `double *dn` that would use the NumPy C API to do the conversion.

Comment: The problem with a typemap for `double *dn` etc. is that there is no way to access the size information. A typemap for `element *` did the trick though, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write helper functions that take an "element *" and return the element you seek:

```
double element_get_weight(const element *elt, unsigned n) {
    assert(n < elt->ngi);  /* or similar */
    return elt->weight[n];
}
```

If you need to modify as well as read, you will want separate "getters" and "setters", of course.

SWIG should be able to wrap all of these easily and expose them to Python.

Performance might not be great, but probably no worse than the alternatives.

Comment: This would have been my last resort, since it's both cumbersome to add these getters and setters and even more so to use them from python. Performance is not really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent to the SWIG created module using `ctypes` looks as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
from numpy import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("_get_element.so")

class ELEMENT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dim", c_int),
                ("vertices", c_int),
                ("quadrature_degree", c_int),
                ("polynomial_degree", c_int),
                ("ngi", c_int),
                ("quadrature_familiy", c_int),
                ("weight", POINTER(c_double)),
                ("l", POINTER(c_double)),
                ("n", POINTER(c_double)),
                ("dn", POINTER(c_double))]

cget_element = lib.get_element
cget_element.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int, POINTER(ELEMENT)]
cget_element.restype = None

def get_element(dim, vertices, quad_degree, poly_degree):
    e = ELEMENT()
    cget_element(dim, vertices, quad_degree, poly_degree, byref(e))
    weight = asarray([e.weight[i] for i in xrange(e.ngi)], dtype=float64)
    l = asarray([e.l[i] for i in xrange(e.ngi*e.dim)], dtype=float64).reshape((e.ngi,e.dim))
    n = asarray([e.n[i] for i in xrange(e.ngi*e.vertices)], dtype=float64).reshape((e.ngi,e.vertices))
    dn = asarray([e.dn[i] for i in xrange(e.ngi*e.vertices*e.dim)], dtype=float64).reshape((e.ngi,e.vertices,e.dim))
    return weight, l, n, dn
```