# How to properly declare this function?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, function-declaration

```
char*[] makeList(char *path, int *noOfFiles);
```

I think my intentions are clear but this doesn't work.

P.S. I need to store the return value in a variable called `char *fileList[260]` and not `char** fileList.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to return an array of pointers from a function unless it is wrapped inside `struct`. If you tried to return an array, it would decay into a pointer value, so the return result would actually be a pointer.

Even if you managed to return an array of pointers somehow, you would not be able to assign it to the variable `fileList` if it is defined as `char *fileList[260]`. As `fileList` is an array type, you are forbidden from assigning to an array.

If you want a function to modify the contents of an array (or *populate* the array), you need to pass the array to the function.

```
int makeList(char *path, int *noOfFiles, char *listOfFiles[], int maxFileCount);

/*...*/
char *fileList[260];
int fileCount;
int result = makeList("/some/path", &fileCount, fileList,
                      sizeof(fileList)/sizeof(*fileList));
```

Your `makeList()` function should make sure it does not write more than `maxFileCount` entries into `listOfFiles`. It can return a result indicating that it needs a larger array if there are more files to return than what the array passed in can hold.

Comment: Probably you meant "... should make sure it does **not** write more ..."

Answer (score 1):

`char *fileList[]` and `char **fileList` are (or can be, anyway) functionally the same. In C, if you are passing or returning arrays, you should (probably) be using only pointers. There are some instances where it is allowed to use arrays (namely if the length of the array is known at compile-time), but it's (in my opinion) easier to just get comfortable with pointers.

Also, this question has more or less been answered already: [Declaring a C function to return an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453410/declaring-a-c-function-to-return-an-array)

Comment: Actually they're not the same in my case.
I need to send this fileList to qsort function which needs to know the size of each element in the array beforehand.

So variable size strings aren't an option.

Comment: The pointers can point to fixed-size areas of memory, and the `fileList[i][j]` syntax will still work. If you change your `qsort` function to accept a `char **`, it should still work as expected.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy The OP has no idea what s/he is talking about in re qsort ... see his/her recent question about it. Hopefully s/he learned something from that.