# Returning a 2-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, types, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, signature

This is dumb, but I'm having trouble getting the right type signature or something. I want to have a function return a two-dimensional array (fixed size on one dimension, variable on the other) but I'm doing something wrong. Minimal example:

```
void useit(unsigned long sz) {
    uint32_t arr[sz][8] = makeit(sz);
    // Do something useful with arr here
}

// Stub function for allocating and filling an array
uint32_t (*makeit(ulong sz))[8] {
    uint32_t (*arr)[8] = malloc(8*sz*sizeof(int));
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 10*i+j+11;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But I don't have the signature right, because gcc complains:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint32_t[8]' from type 'uint32_t (*)[8]'

Comment: What is the `(*makeit(ulong sz))[8]` supposed to do?

Comment: @tkausl: It's trying to be the signature of the function `makeit` which returns a pointer to `arr` (or something like that).

Comment: I see... looks like gibberish to me but maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453410/declaring-a-c-function-to-return-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
uint32_t arr[sz][8] = makeit(sz);
```

since VLAs may not be initialized.

Use:

```
uint32_t (*arr)[8] = makeit(sz);
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/iuqtlJ.

Comment: What should the `makeit` signature be then?

Comment: @Charles, It can remain unchanged.

Comment: It doesn't compile unchanged, or with `uint32_t (*)[8] makeit(unsigned long sz)`.

Comment: Works for me and at http://ideone.com/iuqtlJ after changing `ulong` to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Yes, `ulong` is just a typedef for `unsigned long` in this project, sorry. I'll study your example, thank you very much!